# Maximising an integral.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

> Given that $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7\}$ is any permutation of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$, I am asked to maximise $$\int_{\int_{x_1}^{x_2} x_3}^{\int_{x_4}^{x_5} x_6} x_7 \ \ dx$$

**My work**:

Knowing that $\int c \ \ dx = cx$, the integral in question becomes

$$x_7 \cdot \int^{x_6(x_5-x_4)}_{x_3(x_2-x_1)} 1 \ \ dx$$
This becomes:

$$x_7(x_6(x_5-x_4)-x_3(x_2-x_1))$$

So we are supposed to maximise this expression over distinct integers from $1$ through $7$. I do not know how to proceed, with a pen and paper approach, so I will appreciate help!

Comment: $x_5\gt x_4$.  Can you find whether $x_6$ is above or below $x_5$ or $x_4$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "above or below" there.

Comment: There are three options.  Is $x_6$ above $x_5$,or below $x_4$, or neither?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reduce the $7!=5040$ options a lot.
Suppose $a\gt b\gt c\gt0$.  Let $A=a(b-c),B=b(a-c)$ and $C=c(a-b)$.  Then $A-B=c(b-a)\lt 0$ and $B-C=a(b-c)\gt0$ so $B$ is the greatest of the three options.
So $x_5\gt x_6\gt x_4$ and $x_1\gt x_3\gt x_2$.  That reduced the options by two factors of $6$, to leave $140$ options.
In the same way, $x_7$ is greater than both $x_3$ and $x_6$.  Since $x_3\gt x_2$ and $x_6\gt x_4$, so $x_7$ is greater than at least four other numbers, and must be $5,6$ or $7$.
There are ten ways to divide the other six into two groups of three, so we are down to $30$ options.
The 30 options could be done on one piece of paper.

Comment: +1 A similar argument shows that $x_7$ must be $6$ or $7$: Without loss of generality $x_4=1$. If $x_7<x_5$ then
$$x_7(x_6(x_5-x_4)+x_3(x_1-x_2))-x_5(x_6(x_7-x_4)+x_3(x_1-x_2))=(x_5-x_7)(x_4x_6-x_3(x_1-x_2)).$$
Note that $x_6\leq 6$ and that $x_3(x_1-x_2)\geq6$ because $x_4=1$. This shows that the above is not positive, and so $x_7>x_5$ for some maximal choice of $x_i$'s. This leaves only $16$ options to check, as this also shows that for $x_7=6$ you cannot have $1$ and $7$ in the same group.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have derived a simpler form for your integral already. Continuing from there, to maximise it,

We must notice that the quantity
$$x_6(x_5-x_4)-x_3(x_2-x_1)$$
can be a big quantity, and the function will be maximized when the number that is being multiplied to it, $x_7$, is maximum. So, obviously we choose $x_7=7$.

Now, consider,
$$x_6(x_5-x_4)-x_3(x_2-x_1)$$
Here, from the same logic we used for $x_7$, it is apparent that $x_6=6$, and we would like to maximize $x_5-x_4$ as well. We already picked $6$ and $7$, and for $x_5-x_4$ to be maximum we want $x_5$ to be maximum and $x_4$ to be minimum. So, we choose $x_5=5$ and $x_4=1$ implying that there difference is 4 and $x_6(x_5-x_4)=24$. But, it is easy to notice that with $x_6=5$ and $x_5=6,x_4=1$ we get the same quantity to be 25. So, like we first thought, $x_6\neq 6$. Now, we have $\left\{x_3,x_2,x_1\right\}=\{2,3,4\}$ and since we want to minimise $x_2-x_1$ we choose $x_1=4$ and $x_2=2$, so the only choice for $x_3=3$. Plugging all these values into the function we want,
$$7\left[5(6-1)-3(2-4)\right]=7\times 31=217$$

This is obviously not a rigourous mathematical proof that 217 is the maximum of the given function, but it is the thought process that we are supposed to have in order to solve such a question. Since we have 7 distinct quantities, I doubt that there even exists a rigorous mathematical proof.

Comment: "Since we have 7 distinct quantities, I doubt that there even exists a rigorous mathematical proof." Since we have 7 distinct quantities, we know that there obviously exists a (certain tedious) rigorous mathematical proof. (Though one would prefer a non-tedious one.)